# MediaPlayer won't stop when pressing back button

Tags: android, webview

I'm new to Android and I have to make an App which connects to a NAS in order to play music.
The NAS generates conntects to an HTTP adress where the musicplayer is.
I made a webview in order to display the page, everything works correctly but when I press the back button, I go on the precedent page of my app but the music continues to play until the end of the song. When I open another page there are two songs being played at the same time - the old song and a new one.

How can I kill the mediaplayer when I press the back button? 
I tried different solutions found on the net but nothing works, perhaps because I didn't create the mediaplayer's part seperatly.

Here's the code :

```
package com.example.enrichissementmultimedia;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Baroquisme extends Activity {

 private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_baroquisme);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.14:5000/as/sharing/xJTGwkn3");
    }
}
```

Thank you and sorry for my english !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ovverride `onStop` and clear the WebView content

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity's `onPause()` method, call `mWebView.onPause()`. To get more complicated, you should also call `mWebView.onResume()` in your activity's `onResume()` method if you have previously called `mWebView.onPause()`